# A table is required when uploading new excel file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I created a flow to send emails from excel with Power Automate. When I uploaded new excel file in SharePoint, in flow at List rows present in a table action > Table is error

Here's the flow:

[image]

Comment: What is the expression used for table property? You have to provide the exact name of your table from same excel file.

Comment: Can I use the new excel? But in the files I upload to sharepoint, I always set the table name to the same name.